# How to change the label color (categoryAxis.categories)?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

Tell me please.
How to change the label color of a specific inscription in the axis with categories (categoryAxis.categories = ["2016","2017"])

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **[visual property](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-categoryAxis.labels.visual)** of the categoryAxis.labels to control how the labels look.

```
categoryAxis: {
    categories: [1952, 1956, 1960, 1964, 1968, 1972, 1976, 1984, 1988, 1992, 1996, 2000, 2004, 2008, 2012],
    labels: {
      visual: function(e) {
        var l = e.createVisual();
        if (e.text == '1968' || e.text == '2000'){
            l.children[0].options.fill.color = "#ff0000";
        }
        return l;
      }
    }                  
},
```

## **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/aRIPaN)**